# ExtJS6: Admin Dashboard template is not rendering dashboard when redirected from login view

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am using Admin Dashboard Template and made it to redirect to `dashboard` on successful login. But to my surprise it removes login dialog, successfully changes route hash to `#dashboard` but do not render dashboard. Still showing background image

Here is code snippet on login success callback

```
me.getView().destroy();
me.redirectTo('dashboard');
```

without any success

UPDATE (Here is code flow and snippet)

As mentioned AdminDashboard template is being used. Here are the routes

```
routes: {
  'login' : 'loginView',
  ':node': {
    before: 'isUserLoggedIn',
    action: 'onRouteChange'
  }
},
```

As evident request is halted if user is not logged in and rerouted to login view (as intended)

Once user submit credentials same is checked via backend, on success user re-routed to dashboard

```
onLoginButtonClick: function() {
  var me = this;
  var values = Ext.getCmp('userLoginForm').getValues();
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'api/user/login',
    params: values,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response, opts) {
      me.getView().destroy();
      me.redirectTo('dashboard');
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('login Failed');
    }
  });
}
```

This works as intended , fires request to backend, backend returns with status 200 (when credentials are correct)

But after this login dialog disappears, and routes hash gets changed to `#dashboard` but page still show backend image used in login view (Admin dashboard template)

I think this should be clear now
There are no JS error seen in console
It is just that image is not getting removed
refreshing same gets dashboard page as expected

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This could be because your `me` reference isn't pointing to the right place (Although I'm surprised you aren't getting any JS errors).
Could you try

   ` success: function(response, opts) {
    var w = loginbutton.up('window');
      w.hide();
      w.redirectTo('dashboard');
    }`
Make sure you pass a reference to the `loginbutton` in your on `onLoginButtonClick` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some html debugging, I finally solved this. Here is how I got it working

Admin dashboard login Window has separate layout, other than main, that includes background image.

Redirecting to another page (once login is successful) removes loginWindow view not its layout, and renders main layout with routed view; Leaving loaking window still in front of it. So one need to destroy locking window as well. Here is how I have done that

```
var lockingwindow = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('lockingwindow')[0]
if(lockingwindow)
  lockingwindow.destroy();
```

Comment: I have the same issue but the workaround is not working:i see that the redirect changes just the hash but does not load the main component